# Pandas getting the mean of columns in multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a pandas multi index dataframe like shown below.

```
                   M                            EM                             A            ...        EA                  M0                           EM0                    
Component         EN        EZ        NZ        EN        EZ        NZ        EN        EZ  ...        EZ        NZ        EN        EZ        NZ        EN        EZ        NZ
Date                                                                                        ...                                                                                
2020-07-15  0.001682  0.000963  0.001292  0.000737  0.000635  0.000907 -0.048716  0.022769  ...  0.013103  0.016042  0.003619  0.001009  0.001718  0.000829  0.000685  0.000880
2020-07-16  0.000198  0.000178 -0.001219  0.000586  0.000548  0.000691  0.014514  0.009234  ...  0.010467  0.013240  0.000271  0.000238 -0.001365  0.000592  0.000541  0.000750
2020-07-17  0.000810 -0.000322 -0.000682  0.000445  0.000654  0.000595  0.045604 -0.014437  ...  0.014070  0.011086  0.000966 -0.000665 -0.000886  0.000680  0.000564  0.000584
2020-07-18  0.000287 -0.000887 -0.000329  0.000631  0.000815  0.000534  0.038145 -0.001408  ...  0.016091  0.010116 -0.000147 -0.000928 -0.000342  0.000760  0.000654  0.000519
2020-07-19  0.000805  0.000673 -0.001189  0.000537  0.000513  0.000462  0.051083  0.026574  ...  0.010684  0.009200  0.000746  0.001316 -0.001138  0.000896  0.000493  0.000470
```

I need to calculate the mean of `EN`, `EZ`, and `NZ` columns under `M` and `EM` to new columns (e.g. `Mean`) (also under `M` and `EM`, respectively), like shown below.

```
                  M                                         EM                                                   
Component         EN        EZ        NZ       Mean         EN        EZ        NZ        Mean        
Date                                                                                                                                                          
2020-07-15  0.001682  0.000963  0.001292   x.YYYYYY   0.000737  0.000635  0.000907    y.ZZZZZZ
```

Can someone show me a workaround for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please provide your dataset as dataframe constructor, it is a pain to copy/paste text data with MultiIndexes

Comment: @mozway. I updated my answer with a MRE if you want.

Comment: @Corralien looks like you already have it covered ;)

Comment: I don't think my answer is very good :( Use concat with a single dataframe, it's not very usual.

Comment: @Corralien it's actually a classical method to add a index level, you just reinvented it ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
df_mean = pd.concat({'mean': df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).mean()}, axis=1).swaplevel(axis=1)
df = df.join(df_mean).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
print(df)

# Output:
            EM                 M              
Component   EN  EZ  NZ  mean  EN  EZ  NZ  mean
Date                                          
2020-07-15   4   5   6   5.0   1   2   3   2.0
2020-07-16  14  15  16  15.0  11  12  13  12.0
```

Setup to be reproducible:

```
import io

s = """\
,M,M,M,EM,EM,EM
Component,EN,EZ,NZ,EN,EZ,NZ
Date,,,,,,
2020-07-15,1,2,3,4,5,6
2020-07-16,11,12,13,14,15,16
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), header=[0, 1], index_col=0)
```

**Update**

> I was wondering how may I calculate the median under EM instead of mean.
> I want to have only the mean for M and only median for EM

```
df1 = pd.concat([df['M'].mean(axis=1), df['EM'].median(axis=1)], 
                keys=[('M', 'mean'), ('EM', 'median')])
df = df.join(df1.unstack('Date').T).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
print(df)

# Output:
            EM                  M                   
Component   EN  EZ  NZ median  EN  EZ  NZ       mean
Date                                                
2020-07-15   4   6   6    6.0   1   3   3   2.333333
2020-07-16  14  17  16   16.0  11  11  13  11.666667
```

Comment: Hi @Corralien, Thanks very much for your answer. It seems to do the work for me. I was wondering how may I calculate the median under EM instead of mean. Do you have any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: I tried using `median` instead of `mean`. Then it calculates only `median` for both `EM` and `M`. I want to have only the mean for `M` and only median for `EM`

Comment: @PasHer. I updated my answer. Is it what you expect now?

Comment: Awesome, that is what I was expecting! Thanks very much @Corralien.